# SQL Code displaying duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql

Had this code working this morning, went to lunch, and now its not displaying the correct results.  It is displaying the correct amount of rows that are supposed to show up, but all of the results are duplicates of the first row.

```
SELECT 
    client_main.serial, 
    client_main.make, 
    client_main.model, 
    client_deploy.ticket,  
    client_deploy.techID, 
    client_deploy.installDate, 
    client_deploy.updateDate, 
    client_main.status, 
    client_main.type, 
    client_software.operating, 
    client_software.operating_license, 
    client_profile.buildID, 
    client_profile.department, 
    client_main.warrentyStart, 
    client_main.warrentyEnd, 
    client_hardware.cpu, 
    client_hardware.memory, 
    client_hardware.diskSpace1, 
    client_hardware.diskSpace2, 
    client_hardware.diskSpace3, 
    client_software.antivirus, 
    client_software.antivirus_version, 
    client_software.office, 
    client_software.office_license
FROM 
    client_main, 
    client_deploy, 
    client_hardware, 
    client_network, 
    client_profile, 
    client_software
WHERE client_main.id = client_deploy.id
    AND client_deploy.id = client_hardware.id
    AND client_hardware.id = client_profile.id
    AND client_profile.id = client_software.id
```

UPDATE:

Fixed the code according to the errors pointed out. Now the query is only showing a single result.

```
SELECT client_main.serial, client_main.make, client_main.model, client_deploy.ticket, client_main.status, client_software.operating,  client_profile.username, client_hardware.cpu, client_hardware.diskSpace3, client_software.antivirus, client_network.ip

FROM client_main 
inner join client_deploy on client_deploy.id = client_main.id
inner join client_hardware on client_hardware.id = client_main.id
inner join client_network on client_network.id = client_main.id
inner join client_profile on client_profile.id = client_main.id
inner join client_software on client_software.id = client_main.id
```

Sample Result:

```
serial  make    model   ticket  status  operating   username    cpu diskSpace3  antivirus   ip
123 Delld   Lattitude1  654897  2   4   dhenning1   13  13  4   2
```

Solution Query:

```
SELECT client_main.serial, client_deploy.ticket, client_software.operating, client_profile.username, client_hardware.cpu, client_network.ip
FROM client_main
INNER JOIN client_deploy ON client_deploy.id = client_main.id
INNER JOIN client_hardware ON client_hardware.id = client_main.id
INNER JOIN client_profile ON client_profile.id = client_main.id
INNER JOIN client_network ON client_network.id = client_main.id
INNER JOIN client_software ON client_software.id = client_main.id
```

Comment: What did you have for lunch? ;)

Comment: @GolezTrol, the same thing he has every day, apparently.  ;)

Comment: Would you be able to provide some feedback as to what an example result set looks like that you are now getting and an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: Are all those ids supposed to be the same? It seems to me that a profile id is different from a software id, although it's hard to tell without a more detailed description of the tables and their relationships.

Comment: we need a SQL Fiddle to help you here.  There is not enough information at the moment.

Comment: Just in general, it really helps to cut your examples down by removing extra columns that aren't important to solving the problem, while still demonstrating what is going wrong.

That gives your StackOverflow minions less redundant stuff to read. As a bonus, it often shows you the solution before you hit "Post Question."

Comment: All of the ID's are the same. Sample result posted

Comment: @catfood Result Example and code has been cut down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your schema:

```
FROM client_main, client_deploy, client_hardware,  
      client_network, client_profile, client_software
```

you are selecting from **six** different tables, but only joining against **four**

```
WHERE client_main.id = client_deploy.id
    AND client_deploy.id = client_hardware.id
    AND client_hardware.id = client_profile.id
    AND client_profile.id = client_software.id
```

You are missing a few joins, that is why you are getting duplicate results.

Comment: Alright. Fixed that part of the code. Started coding and walked away without finishing before lunch.  Problem now, is that it's only showing a single result with this code:

Comment: @Drifterhawk give us a SQL fiddle of the issue.

Comment: Was missing a join with the client_network and also the software table was messed up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be more clear if you use SQL92 syntax for JOIN:

```
SELECT m.serial, m.make, m.model, d.ticket, d.techID, d.installDate, d.updateDate, 
  m.status, m.type, s.operating, s.operating_license, p.username, p.buildID, 
  p.department, m.warrentyStart, m.warrentyEnd, h.cpu, h.memory, h.diskSpace1, 
  h.diskSpace2, h.diskSpace3, s.antivirus, s.antivirus_version, s.office, 
  s.office_license
FROM client_main AS m
INNER JOIN client_deploy AS d ON m.id = d.id
INNER JOIN client_hardware AS h ON d.id = h.id
INNER JOIN client_network AS n ON ...wait woops?!...
INNER JOIN client_profile AS p ON h.id = p.id
INNER JOIN client_software AS s ON p.id = s.id
```

There's no condition in your query for the join to `client_network`.  So you're basically generating a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), multiplying the number of rows in `client_network` by the number of rows resulting from the other joined tables.

As for why this didn't have a problem before you went to lunch, if there was only 1 row in `client_network` before lunch, then the Cartesian product wouldn't be apparent.  I'd guess that you or someone else added some more rows to `client_network` during or after lunch.

PS: I agree with the @GolezTrol's comment, it seems unlikely that the correct column to join on is `id` in *all* of these tables.